# JQuery Autocomplete giving member not found error for browsers < ie 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am building a web page using JQuery and my autocomplete feature started acting up when I started testing it in my IE8.

this is the error I got

```
SCRIPT3: Member not found.

jquery-1.6.4.min.js, line 2 character 29472
```

I searched everywhere and I couldn't find a good solution.

Please Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

Worked